# Little info about AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

---

Hi!

i wonder if there is a maximum number of network calls in a class which extends Asyntask ?

Typically i need to do 2 network requests in order to have to json answers and i need to parse each

json to extract the gps coordinates of an address of a start point and an address of an end point to

show a road between them on a mapView.

Im working with osmdroid.

im asking that before to begin writing any code. i just want to be sure

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do as much as you want inside the `doInBackground()` of an `AsyncTask`.
However, it is recommended to divide your logic into separate classes for readability and better design.

Comment: Thanks i think 2 requests is a reasonable number.